# SQL Script using Left Join returns duplicate rows due to third table join

Tags: sql

I want all orders with delivery dates `07/01 - 07/31` from `Orders` table. I join `Billing_History` table to grab delivery date and other fields I want.

Now I want to join my settlement data from `Drs_Settle_Hist` table.  This table shows multiple rows for one order to I tried a query alone to group which works.

How do I insert my individual `Drs_Settle_Hist` data grouped by `Order_ID` into my query?

Query which returns Multiple rows from `Drs_Settle_Hist`:

```
SELECT     orders.id, billing_history.delivery_date, orders.revenue_code_id,  orders.bill_distance, orders.freight_charge, 
orders.otherchargetotal, orders.total_charge, billing_history.distance, billing_history.linehaul_chg, billing_history.other_charge, 
billing_history.total_charges, billing_history.tractor_id, drs_settle_hist.order_id, drs_settle_hist.order_pay, 
drs_settle_hist.perdiem_pay, drs_settle_hist.total_pay, drs_settle_hist.check_number, drs_settle_hist.pay_date 
from orders

left join billing_history ON orders.id = billing_history.order_id
left join drs_settle_hist on orders.id = drs_settle_hist.order_id


WHERE     orders.ordered_date  between '2013-01-01 00:00:00.000' and '2014-07-31 23:59:59.000' and billing_history.delivery_date 
between '2014-07-01 00:00:00.000' and '2014-07-31 23:59:59.000' and drs_settle_hist.is_void = 'N'
```

This query works to group by order_id by itself:

```
Select drs_settle_hist.order_id, sum(drs_settle_hist.order_pay) as OrderPay,sum(drs_settle_hist.perdiem_pay) as PerDiemPay, sum(drs_settle_hist.total_pay) as TotalPay 
from drs_settle_hist where drs_settle_hist.delivery_date between '2014-07-01 00:00:00.000' and '2014-07-31 23:59:59.000' 
group by order_id
```

Where and how can I get this into my original query?

Comment: which columns do you want to include? u got `check nums` and `paydate` there which might be different for same orders?

Comment: I don't have to have check numbers and paydate - although at some point I would like those.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by replacing the join to `drs_settle_hist` with a join to your grouped query on that table, summing up all the amounts per `order_id`. Something like this:

```
SELECT     
  orders.id, 
  billing_history.delivery_date, 
  orders.revenue_code_id,  
  orders.bill_distance, 
  orders.freight_charge, 
  orders.otherchargetotal, 
  orders.total_charge, 
  billing_history.distance, 
  billing_history.linehaul_chg, 
  billing_history.other_charge, 
  billing_history.total_charges, 
  billing_history.tractor_id, 
  settle_hist.order_id, 
  settle_hist.order_pay, 
  settle_hist.perdiem_pay, 
  settle_hist.total_pay, 
  settle_hist.check_number, 
  settle_hist.pay_date 
FROM orders
LEFT JOIN billing_history ON orders.id = billing_history.order_id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT  
             order_id, 
             sum(drs_settle_hist.order_pay) as OrderPay,
             sum(drs_settle_hist.perdiem_pay) as PerDiemPay, 
             sum(drs_settle_hist.total_pay) as TotalPay,
             check_number,
             pay_date
           FROM drs_settle_hist
           GROUP BY order_id) settle_hist ON orders.id = settle_hist.order_id
WHERE     
  orders.ordered_date between '2013-01-01 00:00:00.000' and '2014-07-31 23:59:59.000'
  and billing_history.delivery_date between '2014-07-01 00:00:00.000' and '2014-07-31 23:59:59.000' 
  and drs_settle_hist.is_void = 'N'
```

N.B. This assumes that the two columns you didn't include in your working query (`check_number` and `pay_date`) are not unique across the multiple rows per `order_id`

Comment: thank you for your assistance.  I was able to get the data grouped for OrderPay, PerDiemPay, and TotalPay; however, I receive an error message when trying to obtain drs_settle_hist.check_number and drs_settle_hist.pay_date... "invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or a group by clause" I had it listed in both original select statement on top and listed in left join (select....).

Comment: Thats because you should be asking for `settle_hist.check_number` because its coming from the `settle_hist` subquery, not from the `drs_settle_hist` table, which is no longer referenced by the main query.